# Selenium Scroll down on Newly Opened Body

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium python, and would like to scroll down on a page after clicking an element. Clicking the element gives a pop-up menu, and then when I try some scrolling methods they scroll on the original page.

I have selected the body of the new element that has appeared and tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import Keys
driver = webdriver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(pathto)
button.click()
body = driver.find_element_by_css('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

This does not actually do anything as is. However, if I first manually click on the new popup element before doing `body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`, it does scroll.
One way I have resolved this is using `ActionChains` to right click on the body before scrolling down. Directly using `.click()` on the body does not work as it clicks a link in the body.

Are there any better ways to do this? In particular, I am somewhat afraid that the right click menu that opens up when I use my current method may mess with the rest of the scraping. Is there at least a method to guarantee that it does not interfere? Another solution could be somehow "selecting" or clicking on the body element within selenium, so are there any suggestions for this?

Comment: have you tried the js executor approach to scroll down to a particular element?

Comment: I should have added: I want to scroll until the end of an infinite scroll loader, so I plan to stop the scroll loop when the height stops increasing. I guess I do not know how to do this yet either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using END key instead of DOWN key. It's worth a shot:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(pathto)
button.click()

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

You also may need to click the pop-up in order to focus it first:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(pathto)
button.click()

# click popup menu to get it into focus
popup_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath(pathToPopupMenu)
popup_menu.click()

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```